# Grouped products's simple products exempt from shopping cart rule. How to fix?

Tags: ee-1.13, shopping-cart-price-rules

When a simple product (SP) associated to a grouped product is added to the cart, this works differently from a typical configurable-simple product setup. The product added to the cart is actually the simple product itself (as opposed to, say, a configurable product with its associated SP's attributes), and the shopping cart price rules are not being applied because the SPs are not visible. I've tested this by making the SP in the cart visible and price rule applies.

Reference (Promotion -> Shopping Cart Price Rules -> Conditions tab):
It's a simple rule that give a $3 discount if an item in the shopping cart is included in category 547. The product (simple) being added and its parent (grouped) are both in category 547. Action tab filtering is left empty.

[image: Rule]

<s>Where do I start looking to debug and find a solution for this?</s> I'd like to see if it's possible to make these rules apply to the `Not Visible` SPs, but I can't seem to find a place to get started. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you have the simple products not visible? Are the part of a configurable or just the group?

Comment: These SPs are not visible because grouped products (GP) are what's being shown on the front-end. All SPs are invisible and associated with GPs, and there are no configurable products (CP). I had to use GPs instead of CPs because of the way I had to create the product pages.

Comment: It might be as simple as not putting those products into a category and putting the view to Catalog. They won't show up in your store and the cart rules will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment for the products, this is what I recommend.

1. Remove all simple products from any category they might be in. If
   you're only wanting to show the grouped product, they don't need to
   be in one.
2. Set the associated simple products view to "Catalog" so that the cart rules apply properly.

This will prevent you from having to make any changes to the Magento code and should provide the wanted outcome. The cart rules will function properly and the simple products still won't be individually visible.

edit.. this also worked for me.

Group product is in category id 70.
Simple product view is set to "Not visible individually"
Added the product to cart from the group product page and the discount here applied successfully.

[image]

Comment: As I explained, simple products are not visible products on any level, and making them visible is not on option. That's what the grouped products are there for (in place of traditional configurable products). Unless I'm missing your point, I don't understand why you would allow simple products, which are associated to grouped other, to be visible on any level.

Comment: @laketuna Explain why they can't be set to Catalog? Grouped products have no such limitation. Having them set to Catalog does not make them show up in your store. There's no reason to have them set as "Not visible individually". You can even group products that are visible individually with no issues. Grouping is simply another way to display those products, which is why the simple product gets added to the cart and not a "grouped product" in the way a configurable works.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about setting `grouped products` or `simple products` to `Catalog`? You're using the terms interchangeably. Grouped products are already `Catalog,Search`. Simple products cannot be visible on any level because I don't want them to be reached by the customer or any crawlers, intentionally or by accident. Also, remember that this price rule is based on categories. So, I cannot remove them from the category.

Comment: I explain clearly the two steps that would need to happen. The simple products themselves would be set to Catalog, the group item can be set to whatever you please. It would of course require changing the way your cart rule works. You would need to specify the simple products SKUs in the rule and not the category ID. The simple products could then be removed from the category. You would get the same effect, there's almost always multiple ways to achieve goals in Magento. Crawlers wouldn't see the simple product, nor would customers as it wouldn't be in a category.

Comment: Actually speaking of multiple methods. I was able to get a discount with my simple product set to "Not visible individually" by setting the category in the actions tab and leaving conditions blank. I have provided a screenshot and the details of the test in the answer.

Comment: I separately installed a fresh CE 1.8, where I set things up according to your second suggestion, where I set the grouped product to the be visible and none of the simple products to be visible. I did have to assign both products types to the category to get the cart discount to apply, so it works. It seems that the key is to set the `Actions` to filter categories as in JesseC's post, instead of `Conditions` as I have my screenshot.